# Removing Signed document from an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

How can I remove a signed document from an envelope, without voiding the envelope?

Am using RESTAPI call to remove a particular document from the existing envelope. But an error message is thrown:

```
remote server error. Bad Request (400)
```

I am fine with SOAP API or Rest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "purge" the documents from a completed envelope. You can purge either just the documents themselves, or the documents and their meta-data.

You can't purge just one document from an envelope, it's all or none.

Use the [Envelopes: update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) method. Note: see the purge restrictions and permissions issues listed with the method's description.

Set the body of the request to

```
{
  "purgeState": "op"
}
```

Where op is either

- **documents_queued**: Places envelope documents in the purge queue.
- **documents_and_metadata_queued**: Places envelope documents and metadata in the purge queue